# Preencher meta description via javascript o Google interpreta o código?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, seo

Tenho um JSON

```
{"content":{"description":"Descrição do meu site"}}
```

Queria preencher a meta name description via javascript

```
<meta name="description" content="" />
```

Queria saber se o Google vai ler essa informação, se não qual seria a melhor alternativa para fazer?

OBS: o meu site só aceita JavaScript, então tenho que revolver isso com JS

Comment: Tens controlo sobre quando o script corre? Corre antes da página carregar ou _N_ segundos depois (ie: fora do teu controle)?

Comment: @Sergio Tenho o controle de usar GTM para inserir quando a pagina carrega também era essa sua duvida?

Comment: "GTM"? Queres dizer Google tag manager?

Comment: @Sergio Isso mesmo Sergio

Answer (score 0):

sim o google bot vai respeitar e se comportar igual um elemento html.

uma boa pesquisa no google sobre "does google search process javascript", pode te ajudar a aprofundar até onde você pode usar JS no seu site sem afetar o SEO.